# Adding gestures to uiimageview in uiscrollview (pan, doubletap, pinch)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming, uigesturerecognizer

Currently i am trying to create some kind of an imageviewer, where you can click on an image which is then displayed in full size. Now i want to add gestures to it to zoom. I want to understand and see how to add the pinch gesture to zoom in and out, to be able to pan around the image and to zoom in quickly with the double tap gesture. I did not found much good tutorials.

I know that you zoom into the view, not into the image. That is why you use a ScrollView containing an ImageView. Now what is missing to enable zooming, pinching and moving the image around?

Thank you in advance for any helpful post.

In the following is "my" current code base for this feature. What needs to be added?

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    scrollView=UIScrollView()
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: (self.view.frame.height - (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)! + 44))
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale=3
    scrollView.bounces=false
    scrollView.delegate=self
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    imageView=UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "inlinelogo.jpg")
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height - (44 + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height))
    imageView.backgroundColor = .black
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?
    {
    return imageView
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable imageView userInteractionEnabled property

Answer (score 2):

you missed the `userInteractionEnabled` property of `UIImageView` add

```
imageView.isuserInteractionEnabled = true
```